# Load source code of a private Facebook URL

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication

I am using Facebook login in my Android application.
I can load the source code of any URL which is public on my page and on other pages using ion library
https://github.com/koush/ion

```
private void sourceCode (String url){
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog ;
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, getString(R.string.app_name),
            getString(R.string.waiting), true);
    Ion.with(this).load(url)
            .progressDialog(progressDialog)
            .asString().setCallback(new FutureCallback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Exception e, String result) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

My problem is: When I want to load the source code of a private group link where I am a member like
"https://web.facebook.com/groups/226533317414427/permalink/1514641928603553"

I can do it on the browser by displaying the correct source code. This is because my login and passwords are saved.
When I try on the other browser it gives me the login page. And when entering my login and password it redirects me to the private link.

But on my Android app, it displays the code of the login page with errors.

I think the problem is in the Facebook authentication. But I used Facebook login like this:

```
private LoginButton loginButton;
private CallbackManager callbackManager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_videos"));

    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            goMainScreen();
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),R.string.cancel_login, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),R.string.error_login, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
private void goMainScreen() {
    Intent intent =  new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
}
```

This activity functions without error with a valid access token.

How to load the correct source code on my app like the browser?